# ¿Cómo aplicar las funciones filter o find en el resultado json() de un fetch?

Tags: json, reactjs, fetch

Cuando aplico la función **filter** al resultado de la función **fetch** la consola me dice que `filter`, `find` y otros *no son funciones* y necesito recorrer esos elementos.

El código es tal que así:

```
fetch(url)
.then(res => res.json())
.then(result => {
    console.log(result.filter(user => user == 'usuario'))
})
```

En la consola me sale que filter no es una función.

Quizás lo estoy haciendo de manera errónea, y si es así, ¿me pueden indicar cómo puedo hacerlo?

Comment: Te sugiero revisar la ortografía de la pregunta.

Comment: no se si eres ingles y al traducir me sale que hablas español y por eso las faltas de ortografia no se te traducen bien, o simplemente en vez de ayudar con el problema buscas faltas de ortografia

Comment: Seguramente será porque esas funciones se aplican sobre arrays, y tu lo estas intentando sobre un objeto, que a su vez debe contener el array que esperas recorrer, pero no lo estas apuntando bien.  Cómo no has puesto la estructura de tus datos obtenidos poco más se te puede decir. Haz un console.log(result) para ver que propiedad contiene el array que quieres recorrer y llámalo correctamente al hacer el find/filter/etc.

Comment: Gracias, entendí el problema, lo haré :)